# Inverting quasi-equivalences between DG categories

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I am recently trying to learn the language of DG categories and I have a question concerning the notion of quasi-equivalence.

According to the definition, which you can find for instance on Keller's paper "[On differential graded categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601185)", for a given DG functor $F \colon \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ to be a quasi-equivalence means that for all $X,Y \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{A})$ the induced map
$$
F_{X,Y} \colon \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}^{\bullet}(X,Y) \rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{B}}^{\bullet}(F(X),F(Y))
$$
of chain complexes is a quasi-isomorphism, and moreover that the induced functor 
$$
H^0(F) \colon H^0(\mathcal{A}) \rightarrow H^0(\mathcal{B})
$$
on the level of categories is essentially surjective.

Now, in ordinary category theory, a given functor $F \colon \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is an equivalence of categories if and only if one can find another functor $G \colon \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ such that $F \circ G \cong \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{B}}$ and $G \circ F \cong \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{A}}$. This so-called ``quasi-inverse'' turns out to be unique up to natural equivalence.

**My question is the following:** Given a quasi-equivalence $F \colon \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is it possible to find a quasi-equivalence $G \colon \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ together with DG natural isomorphisms $F \circ G \cong \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{B}}$ and $G \circ F \cong \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{A}}$?

Here, by a DG natural isomorphism between two DG functors $F,G \colon \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$, I mean a DG natural transformation $\varphi \colon F \Rightarrow G$ of degree $0$, as defined for instance in Genovese's paper "[The uniqueness problem of dg-lifts and Fourier-Mukai kernels](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03759.pdf)", such that $\varphi(X)$ is an isomorphism for all $X \in \mathrm{Ob}(X)$.

Comment: In general, I think the answer should be no. Think about it like this: if you are given a morphism of chain complexes which is a quasi-isomorphism, you have an inverse map on the homologies, but these inverse maps in general do not lift to a map of complexes.

Comment: An example of this is the following: consider the complex $C$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ in degree 0 and 1, with the map "multiply by two" between them. Consider another complex $D$ with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ in degree 1 and zeros elsewhere. There is a chain map $f_{\ast}: C \rightarrow D$ where $f_{1}$ is the quotient $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2$. This induces a quasi-isomorphism, but there is no map $\mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LPK's example in the comments can be upgraded to a counterexample to exactly this situation. Consider two DG-categories $A,B$, both with two objects $0,1$ and morphisms $A(0,0)=A(1,1)=B(0,0)=B(1,1)=\mathbb{Z}$, $A(1,0)=B(1,0)=0$, and finally $A(0,1)=\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ while $B(0,1)=\mathbb{Z}/2$. Then there is a quasi-equivalence $A\to B$ which is the identity on objects and has the usual quasi-isomorphism $A(0,1)\to B(0,1)$ as its only nontrivial morphism action. This is not invertible since $A(0,1)\to B(0,1)$ is not. The problem is that $A$ is not bifibrant as a DG category. This is the model category theoretic condition that, generally, realizes weak equivalences (such quasi-equivalences) as homotopy equivalences-legitimately weakly invertible morphisms. The bifibrant DG-categories are difficult to describe fully explicitly, but at the very least the hom-complexes must be levelwise projective (or perhaps injective, in a different model structure.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This pretty much settle it!

Comment: @AGall Thanks! If you're satisfied with an answer, you can click the check mark in the upper left to accept it-the question then gets removed from the list of unsettled questions.

Comment: @AGall You can find other examples in Töen's *Lectures on dg categories*. One can usually upgrade, like Kevin did, a counterexample on the dg algebra level or chain complex level to one of dg categories.